# boost python with template class

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

I created a ring buffer and I want to import that class to Python using boost. When I am trying to that its getting error.

```
ring.cpp: In function ‘void init_module_ring()’:
ring.cpp:130:16: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 4)
 class_<Ring>("Ring").Please help me. Thanks in Advance.
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::python;


template <class T>
class Ring
   {
   public:
   class iterator;
   public:
    unsigned int m_size;
    unsigned int pos;
    T *val;
    Ring():
    m_size(0),pos(0),val(NULL){};
    Ring(int size):m_size(size),pos(0){
        val=new T[m_size];
    };
    Ring(const Ring &other)
        {
        this->m_size = other.m_size;
        this->pos= other.pos;
        this->val = other.val;

        }
    ~Ring()
        {
        delete[] val;
        }
    void insert(T data)
        {
        val[pos]= data;
        pos++;
        if(pos==m_size)
        pos=0;

        }
    void displayall()
    {
       for(int i =0;i<m_size;i++)
       {
       cout<<val[i]<<' ';
       }
    }
    iterator begin()
    {
       return iterator(val);
    }
    iterator end()
    {
       return iterator(val + m_size);
    }
    unsigned int size()
    {
       return m_size;
   }
   void check()
   {
      cout<<val<<' ';
      cout<<val+5;
   }
    };
template<class T>
class Ring<T>::iterator
{
   T *it_value;
   public:
   iterator():it_value(NULL){};
   iterator(T *value)
   {
   it_value = value;
   };
   iterator(const iterator &other)
   {
       this->it_value = other.it_value;
   }
   friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out,iterator it)
      {
      out<<*it.it_value;
      return out;
      }
   iterator operator++()
      {
      it_value  +=1;
      return (iterator(it_value));
      }
   iterator operator++(const int x)
      {
      it_value = it_value+ x+1;
      return(iterator(it_value));
      }
   bool operator==(const iterator &other) const
       {
       return (*it_value == *(other.it_value));
       };
   bool operator!=(const iterator &other) const
   {
   return (!(*this == other));
   };
   iterator operator*()
      {
      return *this;
      }
   void display()
       {
       cout<<*it_value<<' ';
       }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(ring)
{
    class_<Ring>("Ring")
        template <class T>
        .def(init<int>())
        .def("insert", &Ring::insert)
        .def("display_all", &Ring::displayall)
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A template is not a class. You need to instantiate your template (i.e. `Ring<int>` instead of `Ring`).

```
class_<Ring<int>>("IntRing", init<int>())
    .def("insert", &Ring<int>::insert)
    .def("display_all", &Ring<int>::displayall)
;
```

Also, the `template <class T>` part in your original code:

```
class_<Ring>("Ring")
    template <class T> // error
    .def(init<int>())
    .def("insert", &Ring::insert)
    .def("display_all", &Ring::displayall)
;
```

is a syntax error. It suggests that you expect to be able to bind to the template in a generic manner, which is unfortunately not possible. The reason is that templates are instantiated at compile-time, i.e. the compiler needs to know the exact types the template is going to be used with. If you are interfacing with python, you can't know that in advance, because it be decided at runtime.

Under the hood, Boost.Python generates wrapper functions that take the `PyObject`s from python and convert them to strongly typed values for your parameters (and your return values back to `PyObject`s). It can only do it because it knows the types to convert the dynamic values to/from.

The best you can do is creating the class that is not generic but instead operates with [python objects](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/object.html).

EDIT: In response to you comment ("error: ‘init’ was not declared in this scope"), I think the problem is that you are only including one Boost.Python header. Either `#include <boost/python.hpp>` or include all other parts that you need (one is init.hpp).

Comment: first one also not working, its gives me error "error: ‘init’ was not declared in this scope".

Comment: Yea i checked with removing this  'using namespace boost::python' . But still getting error.

Comment: I include  init.hpp header, and still getting the same error -'error: provided for ‘template<class T, class X1, class X2, class X3> class boost::python::class_’
 template <class T, class X1, class X2, class X3> class class_; '

Comment: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 4)
 class_<Ring<int> >("IntRing")

Comment: Now getting this error: local/include/boost/python/class.hpp:265:11: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ring.cpp:134:21: note:   cannot convert ‘Ring<int>()’ (type ‘Ring<int>’) to type ‘const char*’
     .def(Ring<int>())
.

Comment: @NibinJose for the `class_` template the problem might be that you need to expose the first constructor as a parameter of `class_` (I assumed it's fine without it based on your code). Other issues, I'm not sure, you are obviously changing the code and expect me to know what you changed? You should post a different question with your changes. [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: How can I call inner class function (from the  iterator class)?.

Comment: @NibinJose I'm glad this helped. If you found the answer useful, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark next to it. Your other comment is a different question, please ask a new one by clicking the Ask Question button.